# How can a value type implement a ref type

Tags: c#, oop

I came across a scenerio where a value type is implementing ref. type.

Just want to know how come is that possible ( what goes behind the scene ?)

A struct is a value type and interface a ref. type but a struct can implement interface without any error...

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

Actually, it does it in two different ways at once.

Firstly, any value-type can be boxed into a reference-typed object instance. This box is invented by the runtime on demand and will implement the interface in the way you expect - i.e. the box will implement any interfaces the value-type implements.

However, the CLI also allows for a "constrained call". A constrained call turns a virtual call into a static call but only in exactly to the scenario where a value type implements an instance method by way of override or interface implementation (otherwise it is implemented by the JIT as a virtual call). In particular generics makes extensive use of constrained calls (the constrained opcode was added at the same time as generics, for exactly this reason).

Comment: +1, you're correct.  I provided examples, but didn't explain why.

Comment: @Gjeltema I was hoping to inspire you to add more detail, not to delete your answer :(

Comment: Well, I could have added more detail - but you already answered it, so there didn't seem to be much point. :)  Worry not - I shall live to answer another day.

Comment: @Gjeltema: I'd love to see your examples.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Nothing fancy, just int and such (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx).  Marc's reply actually answers the question though.

Answer (score 2):

An interface is not a reference type, it's just a contract for how to implement a type.

A variable of an interface type has to be a reference though, as a type that implements the interface can be a reference type. A variable of an interface type has to be able to hold either a reference type or a value type, as both can implement the interface. A value type can be boxed so that it gets a reference, but a reference type can't be "flattened" into a value.

Comment: What does *flattened* mean here .. ?

Comment: @KenKin: Well... flattened... It's supposed to describe how a reference type would be turned into a value type, but it doesn't have any exact meaning, as that is not possible.

Comment: Oh .. thank you. It still difficult for me to understand. Since I'm not sure *flattened* mean a conversion or boxing, or either and including any other ways?

Comment: @KenKin: The closest real thing would be unboxing, but you can't unbox something that wasn't created by boxing in the first place.

Comment: Ah .. it's true. My English is poor, and cannot grasp some special description often. Thank you very much for clear.

Answer (score 1):

Although we all use the word Type to refer to interfaces, and indeed, even the MSDN documentation describes interfaces as *reference Types*, an interface is not a Type in the same sense as any other reference type or any value type.  It is, in a very real sense not a type at all.  It is a contract for a behavior (a set of methods, properties, and events) that a type must contain by having been declared to implement that interface.

```
public interface ITestInterface { }
public class MyClass:ITestInterface { } 

ITestInterface m = new MyClass() as ITestInterface;
var t = m.GetType();
```

You will see that even though variable `m` is declared to be of type `ITestInterface`,  the Type variable `t` is still `MyClass`.

So, even though, for historical reasons we use the word *type* to apply to interfaces,  the "type" of an interface is a very different thing that the type of a concrete object, which is an instance of a class or struct.

to quote from Don Box's *Essential .Net*

> The CLR deals with objects and interfaces types differently than its
>   predecessors (C++ and COM).  In C++ and COM, a given concrete type
>   has one method table per base type or supported interface.  In
>   contrast, a given concrete type in the CLR has exactly one method
>   table. By inference, a CLR-based object has exactly one type handle.
>   This is in stark contrast to C++ and COM, where an object would
>   routinely have one vptr per base type or interface. For this reason,
>   the CLR's `castclass` does not result in a second pointer value in the
>   same way as C++'s `dynamic_cast`  or COM's `Query-Interface`.

Reading this it is clear that an interface, itself, can never have a vptr table, or a `CORINFO_CLASS_STRUCT` as only true concrete objects (reference and value types) can have.  This structure is created and maintained by the CLR for each Type that is loaded by the executing code at runtime.  Again, from *Essential .Net*,

> The `CORINFO_CLASS_STRUCT` contains pointers to two tables that describe
>   all interfaces the type supports.  The `isinst` and `castclass` [CLR]
>   opcodes use one of these tables to determine whether a type supports a
>   given interface.  The second of these tables is an interface offset
>   table that the CLR uses when dispatching virtual method calls made
>   against interface-based object references.

As can be seen clearly from these references, an interface is a fundamentally different kind of thing than a reference type (a class), or a value type (a struct).  Every object (reference type) or value type instantiated or used within .Net must be a concrete instance of either a class, or a struct. And every object or struct loaded by the CLR has a reference to the single CORINFO_CLASS_STRUCT created for the concrete type of that class or struct.  Intefaces are categories of types, defined so as to guarantee that any class or struct declared to be in that category (declared to implement that interface), must contain a type member (method, property, event, etc.) for each member declared in the interface definition.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are not types in a sense that classes and structs are! Interfaces do not exist by themselves; so they are neither reference type nor value type. You can assign null to a reference. But if the implementer type is a value type, when you assign a variable of that type to another type, it behaves like a value type. And so it behave like a reference type for reference types.

Classes and structs are types for data(code) but interfaces are types for types. They can be used for categorizing other types. They force other types to follow a protocol and nothing more. They are just a layout, a definition, a contract; not an existing thing.

Comment: Interfaces are definitely Types.  There is a difference between a variable being of type `List<T>` or `IList<T>`.  The latter could refer to an instance of the same type as the former, but the reference (as that variable) would still be typed as an interface.

Comment: I did not said they are not types. And the base type of an interface is not System.Object so: "Interfaces are not types in a sense that classes and structs are"; "Classes and structs are types for data(code) but interfaces are types for types".