# Will overriding GetHashCode for a struct cause boxing when used as a key in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

Normally if a struct implements an interface, assigning such struct to an interface variable causes boxing, e.g.:

```
interface IFoo {}

struct S : IFoo {}

S s = ...
IFoo f = s; // boxing here
```

However there are exceptions. It appears that implementing `IEquatable<T>` and using such struct in dictionary as a key, won't cause boxing. So the question is then, what if I just override `GetHashCode` without implementing `IEquatable<T>`? Will it fall into some special case?

Comment: Just try it, actually override GetHashCode().  Call it and see what the MSIL looks like with ildasm.exe.  Your next question about it is [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16744332/17034).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't implement `IEquatable<T>` then the struct will be boxed when calling `Equals`. `Equals` is a virtual method and therefore requires a reference to obtain the associated method table.